# List all Members in a Group including subgroups/projects if Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab-api

Is it possible to have, on a single API call to gitlab, all users of a group and all including subgroups/projects of this group?

I can get a list of all users of a group like that:

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxx" -k "https://gitlab.xxxx/api/v4/groups/319/members?per_page=100&page=1"
```

But it would be irritating to have to do it recursively for subgroups/projects in a script.

Does gitlab provides options to make it recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have not found any API to help me, and then write a script to do that.

```bash
CURRENT_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
GITLAB_SITE="<gitlab site>"
GITLAB_GROUP="<group>"
GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN="<access token>"

#### get projects url #####
url_file=$(mktemp)
temp_file=$(mktemp)
for ((page=1; ; page+=1)); do
  # iterate all pages
  url="${GITLAB_SITE}/api/v4/projects?per_page=100&page=${page}"
  data=$(curl  --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}" $url )
  [ $(jq length <<< "$data") -eq 0 ] && break

  echo "$data" \
  | jq -r --arg GITLAB_GROUP "$GITLAB_GROUP" '.[] | select(.path_with_namespace | startswith("smartcompany")) | [.id] | @csv' \
  | while read -r id; do echo "${GITLAB_SITE}/api/v4/projects/${id}/members/all" >> ${url_file} ; done
done

#### get groups url #####
temp_file=$(mktemp)
for ((page=1; ; page+=1)); do
  # iterate all pages
  url="${GITLAB_SITE}/api/v4/groups?per_page=100&page=${page}"
  data=$(curl  --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}" $url )
  [ $(jq length <<< "$data") -eq 0 ] && break

  echo "$data" \
  | jq -r --arg GITLAB_GROUP "$GITLAB_GROUP" '.[] | select(.full_path | test("^" + $GITLAB_GROUP + "(/|$)")) | [.id] | @csv' \
  | while read -r id; do echo "${GITLAB_SITE}/api/v4/groups/${id}/members/all" >> ${url_file} ; done
done


#### get menbers ####
tmp_members="$(mktemp)"
while IFS= read -r url
do
  for ((page=1; ; page+=1)); do
    url="${url}?per_page=100&page=${page}"
    data=$(curl  --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}" $url )
  [ $(jq length <<< "$data") -eq 0 ] && break

    # data
    echo "$data" | jq -r '.[] | [.id,.name] | @csv' >> $tmp_members
  done

done < "${url_file}"

#### remove duplication ####
members_csv="${CURRENT_DIR}/users-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').csv"
echo "id,name" > "${members_csv}"
sort -n ${tmp_members} | uniq >> "${members_csv}"
```

Answer (score 1):

GitLab offers the option to get the inherited members using:

```
GET /groups/:id/members/all
GET /projects/:id/members/all
```

That will retrieve all the members and permissions through the ancestor groups, but not the children groups. This makes sense since let's say that you retrieve all the users from a group, including those that are only in a single project... How do you know to which project do they belong?

Anyway, [there is an issue from two years ago](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/58367) where they were debating about the implementation of what you require in a single API call, but it doesn't seem that is implemented right now.